# Enviar formulario automaticamente al modificar toggle

Tags: javascript, html

Tengo una duda que me gustaría aclarar, tengo un formulario con un imput de la libreria Bootstrap llamado toggle, es una especie de switch que mueves para encender o apagar.

```
<form method="post" name="Myform" id="Myform" >
  <div class="form-group">
 <label>Definir apagado del sitio</label>
   <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle"   />
    </div>
<input  name="site" id="site"   />
<br />
```

Cuando muevo ese botón, a través de js me carga en un input el valor del botón.

```
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle').bootstrapToggle({
  on: 'Activo',
  off: 'Inactivo',
  });
 $('#toggle').change(function(){
  if($(this).prop('checked'))
  {
   $('#site').val('si');
  }
  else
  {
   $('#site').val('no');
  }
 });
});


// Parte dos envío automático

$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#site').on('onchange', function() {
     document.forms['#Myform'].submit();
  });
});
</script>
```

Valga la pena aclarar que los datos que pretendo recibir del formulario lo hago en el mismo archivo asi:

```
if(isset($_POST['Myform'])){
```

Si pongo un botón para enviar el formulario me funciona sin ningun problema, ahora bien, lo que quiero es que cuando yo le de click al toogle para moverlo a encendido o apagado, este automaticamente haga el envio del formulario, para eso tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#site').on('onchange', function() {
     document.forms['#Myform'].submit();
  });
});
```

A pesar de haber leido en varias partes no logro hacer que se haga el envio del formulario, alguien me puede ayudar por favor?

Aquí dejo el boton como lo tengo:

[DEMO](https://jsitor.com/8jbKeF93Bw)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tienes un par de errores, el primero y más importante es que estás asignando un evento `.on('onchange', ...)` al campo de texto que no se va a disparar, porque debería ser solo `.on('change', ...)` y, además, debe haber intervención del usuario, tecleando contenido y cambiando el foco a otro elemento del formulario.

De acuerdo a lo que mencionas en la pregunta, lo que quieres es que el formulario se envíe al hacer clic en el `switch`, donde ya tienes un evento para manejar los cambios y es ahí mismo donde debes enviar el formulario.

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $('#toggle').bootstrapToggle({
    on: 'Activo',
    off: 'Inactivo',
  });
  $('#toggle').change(function(){
    if($(this).prop('checked')) {
      $('#site').val('si');
    } else {
      $('#site').val('no');
    }
    // Envío de formulario cuando cambia el switch
    $('#Myform').submit();
  });
  // Esto es solo si vas a permitir que el usuario modifique el campo
  $('#site').on('change', function() {
    // Envío de formulario cuando el usuario modifica el contenido del campo "site"
    $('#Myform').submit();
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/js/bootstrap-toggle.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-toggle/2.2.2/css/bootstrap-toggle.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<form method="post" name="Myform" id="Myform" >
  <div class="form-group">
    <label>Definir apagado del sitio</label>
    <input type="checkbox" name="toggle" id="toggle">
  </div>
  <input  name="site" id="site" value="no">
  <br>
</form>
```

En PHP tienes otro error:

```
if(isset($_POST['Myform'])) {
```

No vas a recibir `Myform` porque solo se envía el contenido del formulario y no la etiqueta del mismo. Al menos con lo mostrado en la pregunta, puedes recibir dos campos:

- `togle`, nombre del *checkbox* y se enviará solo si la propiedad `checked` es verdadera
- `site`, nombre del campo de texto, este se enviará siempre

Entonces, la línea para saber si se está procesando el formulario debería ser:

```
if(isset($_POST['site'])) {
```

Comment: Tienes razon, tenia varios errores que impedían que funcionara como quería, ya los corregí, funciono perfecto, mil gracias, ya aprendi algo mas de JS